# Parsing and Editing/Appending a File isn't happening as expected in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have file which I will be parsing repeatedly to check and edit the contents.

Below is the snippet of the insert_code_file.txt.

```
//------------------------------------------
// Define Town Names
//-----------------------------------------

//------------------------------------------
// Define Color Names
//-----------------------------------------

//------------------------------------------
// Define City Names
//-----------------------------------------
```

Below is the snippet of the same file with some information added - insert_code_file1.txt

```
//------------------------------------------
// Define Town Names
//-----------------------------------------

//------------------------------------------
// Define Color Names 
//------------------------------------------
`ifndef DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES
 // blue
 // green 
`endif // DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES

//------------------------------------------
// Define City Names
//-----------------------------------------
```

Wanted to parse the file and add some text accordingly.

For eg:

- In snippet 1, if the ifndef DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES isn't there, then the code need to append ifndef DISABLE_COLOR_NAME and add the respective text and close it with endif.
- If as shown in snippet 2, if the ifndef DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES already exists, then I need to skip adding that line and add the respective text alone and then again check if the endif is there and end accordingly.

Tried below piece of code and kinda works for the first case [but know the code is something wrong] but for the 2nd case it messes up the file.

```
# Import Variables
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
from   Tkinter import *
import string
import ttk
import re
import gzip
import signal
import inspect 
import textwrap

def add_edit_code(filename):
   file_arr = []
   file = open(filename,"r+") 
   fnd1 = 0
   fnd2 = 0
   fnd3 = 0

for lines in file:
   file_arr.append(lines)

   if (fnd1 == 0) and lines.startswith("// Define Color Names"):
      fnd1 = 1
   if (fnd1 == 1) and lines.startswith("//--"):
      fnd1 = 0; fnd2 = 1;
   if (fnd2 == 1) and not lines.startswith("`ifndef DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES"): 
      file_arr.append("`ifndef DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES\n"); fnd2 = 0; fnd3 = 1
   if (fnd3 == 1) and len(lines.strip()) != 0:
      file_arr.append(" // red"); fnd3 = 1; fnd1 = 0;
   else:    
      if (fnd3 == 1) and not lines.startswith("`endif // DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES") and len(lines.strip()) == 0: 
        file_arr.append("`endif // DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES\n\n"); fnd3 = 0
      else:
        continue

file = open(filename, "w")
for lines in file_arr:
   file.write(lines)
file.close()

add_edit_code("insert_code_file.txt")    
add_edit_code("insert_code_file1.txt")
```

For the first file below is the output

[image]

For the 2nd file below is the output.

[image]

Is there any better technique to parse, edit and append for the above scenario?

UPDATED CODE: With some help was able to get passed the issue in a different approach. But faced a different issue like if the ifndef exists @ multiple places, the code inserts the content @ the first occurrence and not at the place where I wanted.

Is there any approach in string process where you can check for a sub string after particular position ?

```
# Global Import Variables
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
from   Tkinter import *
import subprocess
import shlex
import os 
import time
import string
import threading
import sys, argparse
import ttk
import re
import logging
import warnings
import os.path
import gzip
import signal
import inspect
import textwrap


def add_edit_code(filename):
    file_arr = []
    final_file_arr = []
    file = open(filename,"r+") 
    content = '' 

    for lines in file:
        content = content+lines+'|' 

    pos = content.find('`ifndef DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES')
    if pos == -1:
        pos = content.find('// Define Color Names\n')
        apos = pos + len('// Define Color Names\n')+len('//------------------------------------------\n')
        content = content[:apos]+'\n|`ifndef DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES\n| // red;\n|`endif // DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES'+content[apos:]
    else:
        apos = pos + len('ifndef DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES\n')
        content = content[:apos]+'\n // red;|'+content[apos:]

    file = open(filename, "w")
    final_file_arr = content.split('|')
    for lines in final_file_arr:
        file.write(lines)
    file.close()

add_edit_code("insert_code_file.txt")    
add_edit_code("insert_code_file1.txt")
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I would suggest using a context manager to handle files. That `continue` statement in the `lines` loop is unnecessary. In the same loop, I think some of the `if`s could be converted to `elif`s.

Comment: Some more context would be nice, too.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Its like based on some information, I would like calling up the respective file to add/edit/append contents accordingly. Its just one portion of code which I wanted to edit and rest are kinda-off similar, so gave a portion of example.BTW, how does context manager help in handling them ? Haven't tried using them.

Comment: I meant some more information on the context surrounding this particular program. What the data is for, etc. You can find a nice article on context managers [here](https://alysivji.github.io/managing-resources-with-context-managers-pythonic.html).

Comment: @AlexanderCécile: Have some text files which will be used in a bigger program. Based on the user need the file content needs to be updated/edited.

Comment: That’s still not what I’m looking for, not even close... That can describe an immense amount of programs.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I gave a bigger picture of what I intended to do. Wondering what you are looking for ? I just wanted to parse a file and edit some piece/portion of the file and in turn this file gets used in different programs.

Comment: I was curious because the syntax of the file is quite unusual. It looks like code, honestly.

Comment: have you thought about using `awk` for this? I have a hunch that is a better tool for this job than `python` is.

Comment: @BartVanLoon Well this is a problem I have come across in a bigger python code and intended to solve/find a resolution in the same. If it was basic text addition probably would have used awk or something else.

Comment: It’s going to be difficult to help you find a proper solution if you won’t share more information about the program.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I already described my problem and also a basic tried out code. I am confused what you are looking for ? As I told I jst wanted to edit a file [and Yes its some program file] which will be called in some different process. Whenever some change/text needs to be added, I call up my basic python code and once it process the file, which will then be called up in different process.

Comment: @Vimo Alright, so it is code? The content/format of the file is important, it almost single-handedly determines the appropriate solution. For example, if your file was CSV, I might suggest Pandas, if it was HTML, then Beautifulsoup would be the better choice.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Sorry you meant in that way. Well this is not CSV or HTML file and this is basic C/C++ code files which I wanted to edit. Just gave a basic outline of the problem with the code snippet.

Comment: @Vimo Which is it, or C++? In any case, I’m glad I asked, since parsing code is a whole other ballgame. I can do some research, suggest a few libraries and resources, but it’s unlikely I’ll be able to find an answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

You are processing one record at a time, when actually you have to process two records at a time. The current and the next record. For file1.txt, the code

```
file_arr.append("`ifndef DISABLE_COLOR_NAMES\n");
```

gets executed before reading the next line. So `ifndef DISABLE_COLOR_and
 // red gets appended and then 'ifndef DISABLE_COLOR gets appended to file_arr from file1.txt